# Неряха - происхождения корня

Tags: этимология

Неряха, неряшливость - неаккуратность. Но при этом мы можем употребить "не" со словом "аккуратность" раздельно: "Он не аккуратный, а маньяк чистоты", то "неряшливость", "неряха" - это цельная конструкция. А ведь, судя по всему, была какая-то "ряшливость"))) Что же корень этого слова означал с самого начала?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**неряха**

```
Искон. Преф. производное от *ряха* «опрятно одетая», суф. образования (суф. -х-, ср. пряха, сваха) от *рядиться*. См. *наряд*.
```

Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа. Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва. 2004.

http://etymological.academic.ru/3091